# Is it possible to get this glossy shiny texture?

Tags: texturing, light

I'm still learning to use blender 2.8 during my internship. My supervisor have give me a task to make intro video and ask me to get this kind of texture. I have follow many tutorial on youtube but I still can't get this texture. I'm still wondering what did I wrong?

[image: Example of glossy texture that my supervisor ask]

This is the image what my supervisor ask for

[image]

This is the result

[image]

[image]

These two are my work

Comment: hdri can help you to get better reflection

Comment: also I guess adding a color ramp to tweak the colors and adding that streak of gray color in between would help ...... I haven't tried It but I guess it would work.

Comment: Usually these logos are heavily edited in post-processing with softwares like gimp, or famous Adobe iterations. You can do it with a few clicks and simple layers in such softwares whereas to get it physically correct in Blender you will have to get a perfect lighting setup and tweak the shader accordingly, as presented in the answer below. It is however a nice challenge if you want to learn new techniques, but if you have a deadline in a professional setting, you should prioritize the easiest way out.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning doesn't work the way in blender as blender is similar to the real world reflections and the logo containing the reflections are not even close to the reflections in blender. I've tried it my self in blender after seeing this question.

You can see it in this .gif file below as I try to increase the roughness reflections change.

[image]

If you really want to design logo in blender you can using some complex lightning but it won't be as perfect as you wanted, I've tried to make a simple version of what you wanted and this is the final result that I've got. To get this I've put roughness to 0.5 and Clear coat to 1.0[image]

And this is the simple scene that I've made to get the result.

[image]

If you want check out the .blend file

[image]

Simple Answer : To get the logo you required try "Adobe Illustrator" that would make things easy and simple for making logo as most of the logo making is done in Illustrator and also the logos that you've sent are also Vectors if I'm not wrong.

But if you just want to make in blender try the above scene.